# Bower installation not working: could not read Username for 'https://github.com': No such file or directory

Tags: javascript, typescript, bower, chessboard.js

I am trying to install a bower package with the following command:

```
bower install theborakompanioni/angular-chessboard --save
```

When I run the command, I get the following message:

```html
    bower chessboard.js#1.0.0      ECMDERR Failed to execute "git ls-remote --tags --heads https://github.com/theborakompanioni/chessboardjs.git", exit code of #128  Unhandled Exception: System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'GitHub, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.    at Microsoft.Git.CredentialManager.Program.Main(String[] args) bash: /dev/tty: No such device or address error: failed to execute prompt script (exit code 1) fatal: could not read Username for 'https://github.com': No such file or directory Additional error details:
Unhandled Exception: System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'GitHub, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
   at Microsoft.Git.CredentialManager.Program.Main(String[] args)
bash: /dev/tty: No such device or address
error: failed to execute prompt script (exit code 1)
```

Does anyone know how to fix this problem?

I tried goig to the settings of the IDE and checking the "Use credential helper".